# Handling the type of event data in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to convert my JavaScript code into TypeScript (1.8.9) and I am wondering what is the correct way declare or cast the data attached to event.

```
self.onmessage = function(e: Event){
    if(e.data.schedules) processSchedules(e.data.schedules)
};
```

The `data` portion gets marked red by PHPStorm. Should I cast it to some interface or `any` in order to dismiss TS error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your event should be a [`MessageEvent`](https://github.com/cloud9ide/typescript/blob/master/typings/lib.d.ts#L5918), not `Event`:

```
self.onmessage = (e:MessageEvent) => {
    if (e.data.schedules)
        // ...
}
```